# Is M1 Chip Memory Considered as Registers?

Tags: cpu, ram, bus, register

Given the following image of Apple's m1 chip, we can clearly see that RAM is so close to the CPU:

1. does this say that RAM will be much faster when compared to others Macbook models (Since distance is less than by nearly 30x!)
2. Can we consider and treat the RAM in this case as registers? If they are nearly as close as registers what's the difference between them and registers?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No. The difference between RAM and registers is that the bits in the registers directly connect to and control hardware and configurations of hardware. Registers literally do stuff, not just store stuff. Registers don't connect to the CPU.  They *are* the CPU.

Answer (score 2):

It's fast, but it's not similar to CPU registers, and not as fast as you may assume. I don't have hard numbers on the performance of the on-chip interconnect, but it's going to be limited by the latency of the actual RAM array regardless of interconnect savings, and isn't likely to be able to do more than one or a small handful of transactions per cycle. In fact, while your memory is close, it doesn't even look like it's on the same die, meaning that it'll need to cross a silicon interposer or other structure anyway.

Some background on CPU registers: The registers of a typical CPU are tightly integrated with the CPU's pipeline and internal structure, including things like the pipeline being aware of register hazards, renaming, etc.

Even though the RAM is on the same *package*, it's not nearly as close as registers would be. There are intervening memory caches between the RAM and CPU (just like non-SoC CPUs have on-die/on-package caches as well, which are not treated as registers). Further, even though the interconnect is on-chip, it's still a memory bus (e.g. AXI) which is far slower than the register-functional unit interconnect in the CPU.

Finally, there are significant differences in logical organization and addressing: CPU registers are mapped, renamed, and accessed through both their architectural names (e.g. `R0, R1, LR`) plus hardware-driven register renaming to support superscalar operation in the presence of hazards. They can directly control hardware operations (e.g. MSRs or SFRs), while RAM is just bulk storage of information.
Furthermore, the RAM is accessed as a range of physical addresses, translated by a memory management unit using page tables which are controlled by kernel-mode *software*, dissimilar to the registers.

Comment: Thanks, one last thing if the RAM is nearly 32x closer will this make it 32x faster? if not how much improvements apple gained from sticking the RAM next to the CPU rather than putting it as it did with previous generation of macbooks?

Comment: @albert Added notes regarding that. Even if it's closer, you're still limited by the latency of the actual memory (especially if it's DRAM), and while your on-chip interconnect is probably faster than the DRAM bus of an Intel CPU, it's still not likely to be 30x faster.

Comment: could you estimate the performance improvements for write/read speed of RAM?

Comment: @albert I don't feel comfortable speculating based on the information so far available to me about the SoC (and because I have non-public information in the field unrelated to Apple which would bias any estimates I give), beyond what I've already said.

Comment: @albert Moving the RAM closer has no effect on performance as even a single cycle delay at DRAM clock speeds is several feet due to how slow DRAM cell read out is.  Thus all practical DRAM is electrically as close to the CPU as possible. It does save a small amount of power (less wire resistance) and may be cheaper as well if it saves on circuit board space.

Comment: @user1850479 It's actually a very substantial saving in power going on-chip - the main driver is the greatly reduced capacitance (not resistance) so you don't need the big, power hungry transistors to drive the physical interface.

Comment: @awjlogan Going on chip would save a lot of capacitance (no external wires), but they didn't do that.  The memory chips are still external and still on a regular PCB, so I think the main savings is the slightly shorter wires having lower resistive losses allowing a lower voltage, but I could be wrong about.

Comment: @user1850479 Ah sorry, I didn't read the question close enough - doh, of course they didn't go on chip, totally different process etc. The resistance isn't an issue, it's the capacitance that is the problem as you've got to charge/discharge it on each change. The static current is (ideally) 0 as the level is either 1/0, so the only current in the line is to charge/discharge the capacitance.

Comment: @awjlogan For such short traces the capacitance of the line is dominated by the source and load (which will each be multiple pF), not the wiring, so making the wires shorter doesn't make much difference in total capacitance.  Conversely due to skin effect, at these frequencies you are losing at least tens of millivolts per cm, so doesn't take much shortening to turn 1.2v memory in 1.1v memory.  My gut feeling is that this is the biggest savings, but I've never designed such a high frequency circuit so I could be totally wrong.

Comment: @user1850479 Hmm - quick calculation suggests it's a significant capacitance, even for short traces, and I'd be surprised if the noise margin were that low. But, I'm with you, we're well into the RF realm now..! :)